# Disabling touch in Android (only allowing stylus)

Tags: android, android-touch-event

I'm writing an Android 5.1 application for a tablet and I'm able to distinguish between touch and stylus input with the help of the `MotionEvent` object.

Is it possible to only allow stylus input (i.e. touching should have no effect)?

Comment: This [link](http://lapasa.net/knowledge/?p=490) may help you.

Comment: @huk I can distinguish between touch and stylus. What I want to do is to only allow stylus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure there's no better approach but you can create custom view, put it as top-most in your layout (make it take full width and height so it covers whole ares). The view only job would be to handle inputs and "consume" all motion events you want to filter out (ie these  not coming from stylus) by marking them as processed, and ignore all the others,  allowing framework to propagate thru your view hierarchy for regular handling by other views.

**EDIT**

The simplest implementation would be to make your view extend something existing, yet simple, like. `FrameLayout` or `Space` (so you do not need to bother all the measure stuff) and override `onTouchEvent()` to filter all the inputs. If this something you do not want to pass, "consume" it here by returning `true`, otherwise return `false` so it will propagate. 
And important to make your view top-most to overlay all the others, i.e.

```
FrameLayout
   YourCustomView
   PreviousLayout
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Could you make an example to clarify your approach?

Comment: this is pretty straightforward, but see edited answer